# How to make an Angular factory globally active?

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular Websockets to define a factory which is intended to be globally active. The current factory is defined as:

```
  ngApp.factory('FixtureFeed', [
    '$websocket', '$rootScope', function($websocket, $rootScope) {
      var dataStream;
      dataStream = $websocket("ws://" + window.location.hostname + "/");
      dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
        return $rootScope.$broadcast('message', message.data);
      });
      return dataStream;
    }
  ]);
```

And then I simply include it as a dependency on one of my controllers, such as:

ngApp.controller('FixtureCustomCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, FixtureFeed) {
     # other code...
  });

And simply having it there and not touching it further appears to allow it to be active beyond the life of the controller, where by if I switch to a different angular path which calls a different controller, the `FixtureFeed` continues to handle messages and broadcast.

I could include the factory as a dependency on all my controllers, and this appears to work fine, only ever instantiating the factory once and handling each message once, but it feels like a dirty hack of course. I also can't guarantee that any given controller will become immediately active as I have all sorts of routes that could be the entry point to using the app. What is the correct way to handle this please?

Comment: It seems you don't want a service, but instead you want to run some code at startup of the application. That's what ngApp.run() is for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run

Comment: Ahh, you're right, just including FixtureFeed as a dependency in ngApp.run() works fine. thanks!